# How do I bind a domain context to a data grid ? Ria Services + Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm, data-binding, wcf-ria-services

These past days I've tried to understand the concept of invoked methods and domain contexts, but some things are still not so clear to me.

In my StudentDomainService I have this method:

```
[Invoke]
    public IEnumerable<Student> GetStudents()
    {
        return _studentRepository.GetStudents();
    }
```

This returns a list of students that I want to bind to my datagrid using a viewmodel.

In my StudentViewModel I have:

```
private StudentDomainContext _studentDomainContext;
private InvokeOperation<IEnumerable<Student>> _students;
public StudentViewModel()
    {
        _studentDomainContext = new StudentDomainContext();
        _students = _studentDomainContext.GetStudents(OnInvokeCompleted, null);
    }

    public void OnInvokeCompleted(InvokeOperation<IEnumerable<Student>> studs)
    {
        if (studs.HasError)
        {
            studs.MarkErrorAsHandled();
        }
        else
        {
            var result = studs.Value;
        }
    }

    public InvokeOperation<IEnumerable<Student>> Students
    {
        get { return _students; }
        set
        {
            _students = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Students");
        }

    }
```

And in StudentView I have a datagrid and I'm trying to bind to the Students property like this:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Students}"
```

But when I start the application the data grid appears but it's not displaying anything. Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE** I think the problem is that the OnInvokeCompleted() method is not executing on the UI, but I'm not really sure.

Comment: I have to ask - you are maintaining a legacy application, right? Because silverlight has seen the light and gone into it years ago.

Comment: Yes, the firm I'm working at has this application in Silverlight and now I have to familiriaze with it

Comment: Is that your entire implementation of `StudentViewModel`? I don't see a `Students` property.

Comment: @Crowcoder The Students property is right there, though I'm not quite sure I implemented it well..

Comment: I'm not familiar with `InvokeOperation`, is `InvokeOperation<IEnumerable<Student>>` substitute-able for `IEnumerable<Student>` ?

Comment: I don't think so because my first idea was to use IEnumerable<Student> but I got an error saying that the return type is not compatible with IEnumerable, then I changed it like this but now my datagrid is not displaying anything. Maybe I'm doing something wrong so any solution is welcomed

Comment: I hope a silverlight user comes along to help, but I would suggest trying to make `GetStudents` return `List<Student>` like this: `return _studentRepository.GetStudents().ToList();` and making the `Students` property also `List<Student>`. Then debug and make sure the view model `Students` property has data.